# Rails 3 "The action 'method' could not be found for ActionMailer::Base"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Unable to send mail in rails 3. showing following message in browser.

```
Unknown action

The action 'method' could not be found for ActionMailer::Base
```

Here is the code I wrote.

1. Notifier.rb

`class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base 
  default :from => "xxxxx@gmail.com"
  default_url_options[:host] = "localhost.com:3000"`

def welcome_email(user)
    @user_email = user
    @url = root_url
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Welcome to the site")
  end
end

2.UsersController.rb

`Notifier.welcome_email(@user).deliver`

1. application.rb

`config.action_mailer.deliver_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => 'xxxxxxx.com',
      :user_name => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
      :password => 'xxxx',
      :authentication => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }`

Here is the log messages

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound
>   (The action 'method' could not be
>   found for ActionMailer::Base):
>   app/mailers/notifier.rb:1:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in`
>   create'
>
> Rendered
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/unknown_action.erb
>   within rescues/layout (0.0ms)

Comment: Check out there http://asciicasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3 . It worked preety good for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method
```

not

```
config.action_mailer.deliver_method
```

.

I happened to make the same typo in my configuration today.

Comment: Arg -- its spelled wrong in this ruby doc! Evil
http://rubydoc.info/gems/amazon-ses-mailer/0.0.4/frames